# Redhat Enterprise Linux 8.1 USB bootable installation: Cannot detect hard disk and network devices

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I have an AMD Sempron processor which is core unlocked as an Athlon II with 2 cores. 2 SATA HDDs, one of which has Windows 10 installed.

I am trying to install Redhat Enterprise Linux 8.1 from a USB bootable device - made using rufus 3.x version. (Dual boot with windows 10)

The problem is, on boot, anaconda does not detect any of the devices such as the SATA hard disks as well as the network device. The drivers are probably not loaded. Can anyone please help fix this ?

I have created some unallocated free space to install RHEL on the secondary SATA HDD. But the disks are not detected.

I tried creating the bootable USB stick from the binary ISO image (from the Redhat site) using both MBR and GPT partitioning but still no luck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Windows is installed on a MBR or GPT partition?

Comment: You have UEFI so you want GPT/UEFI settings in Rufus and then assure it's booting in UEFI mode (unless Windows has been installed in Legacy mode). The drives not being detected is probably related to the SATA mode: Change RAID or Intel RST to AHCI (but do install AHCI support on Windows or it won't boot with AHCI). Regarding the network drivers you may need to install them after the OS.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows is on MBR

Comment: If Windows is on MBR then you need to keep Legacy Mode/Compatability Mode disabled.  What about the other part of my comment, and why isn't that vital information, contained within your question?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia could not find an option to change RAID to AHCI in bios I’m using an old ASUS M4N68T board

Comment: @Ramhoud  - please clarify what "other part" of your comment you are referring to.